# Trying to get the"name" of a javascript object supplied by an API

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am calling an API which is giving me back, among other things, an array of javascript objects. The objects in the array are named and I need to use the name in the new individual objects I am creating from the array. Problem is, I don't know how to get to the object's name.

```
{
"OldCrowMine.E9001":{"last_share":1524883404,"score":"0.0","alive":false,"shares":0,"hashrate":0},
"OldCrowMine.S9001":{"last_share":1524,"score":"648.24","alive":true,"shares":632,"hashrate":14317274},
}
```

I am after the "OldCrowMine.E9001" bit. I am sure this is quite simple, I just don't know how to search for the answer because I am not sure what to call this. I have tried searching for a solution.

[image]

Comment: `Object.keys(obj)[0]`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Order of keys is implementation dependent and not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, I tried your suggestion and am getting "TypeError: mWorker.keys is not a function".

Comment: @SevilNatas, You did not do it right. Object is a constructor. Look at my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop - or am I missing something? Simplified raw data version.

```js
var raw = {
    "OldCrowMine.E9001":{"share":1524883404},
    "OldCrowMine.S9001":{"share":1524}
};

for(var first in raw) {
    console.log(first +" share -> "+ raw[first]["share"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
"OldCrowMine.E9001":{"last_share":1524883404,"score":"0.0","alive":false,"shares":0,"hashrate":0},
"OldCrowMine.S9001":{"last_share":1524,"score":"648.24","alive":true,"shares":632,"hashrate":14317274},
}
console.log(Object.keys(obj)[0]);
```

Comment: And how should that help to map `OldCrowMine.E9001` to `{"last_share":1524883404,"score":"0.0", ...`?

Comment: @t.niese, But question's author want to get object's name

Comment: That is true I am trying to get the name of the object.

Comment: @SevilNatas, did my answer come up to you?

Comment: @Yernar yes, but in trying to implement it, it is currently returning "last_share" and not the object name.

Answer (score 0):

Get the keys and map the name and the object:

```
var x= {
"OldCrowMine.E9001":{"last_share":1524883404,"score":"0.0","alive":false,"shares":0,"hashrate":0},
"OldCrowMine.S9001":{"last_share":1524,"score":"648.24","alive":true,"shares":632,"hashrate":14317274},
};
var mapped = Object.keys(x).map(function(d,i){return [d,x[d]]});
```

The name is map[n][0] and its object is map[n][1] where n is your item number.